# Dataframe column appears incorrectly sorted

Tags: r

For a dataframe with three columns --

- `$x` -- at http://pastebin.com/SGrRUJcA
- `$y` -- at http://pastebin.com/fhn7A1rj
- `$z` -- at http://pastebin.com/VmVvdHEE

-- I have the following code to generate a dataframe that can be used to plot a stacked bar plot:

```
counted <- data.frame(table(myDf$x),variable='x')
counted <- rbind(counted,data.frame(table(myDf$y),variable='y'))
counted <- rbind(counted,data.frame(table(myDf$z),variable='z'))
```

If I then try to sort the dataframe by its `Var1` column, as so --

```
counted.sort <- sort_df(counted,vars="Var1")
```

-- I get a dataframe in which column `Var1` now has levels in the following order:

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", 19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29",
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 36", 37", "39", "42", "46", "47", "53", "54", "38",
"40", "41", "43", "44", "45", "48", "49", "50"
```

The result distorts the x-axis of my bar plot (...,"54", "38", "40", "41", "43",...).

How can I get `counted.sort` to be sorted correctly by ascending number?

NB. Plotting is done as below:

```
stackedBp <- ggplot(counted,aes(x=Var1,y=Freq,fill=variable))
stackedBp <- stackedBp+geom_bar(stat='identity')+scale_x_discrete('Levels')+scale_y_continuous('Frequency')
stackedBp
```

Comment: How are you plotting currently?  Without knowing that... converting your `Var1` column to `integers` rather than a `factor` will probably solve your problem (see `?factor` for a conversion method).

Comment: @Justin I've tried `integer` but for some reason it bumps the values in `Var1` up by 1, although it does address the ordering problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, R's `?factor` is confusing you.

Let's start with `table`. This command is for cross-classifying observations into different, well, *categories*. Implicit here is that the resulting categories are most often going to be *categorical* rather than *numeric*.

This is why when you pass the table to `data.frame` the table categories are converted to a factor. Inspect the structure of `counted`:

```
> str(counted)
'data.frame':   138 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Var1    : Factor w/ 53 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Freq    : int  126 711 1059 2079 3070 2716 2745 3329 2916 2671 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "x","y","z": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

There's is an important distinction between the levels and the labels of factors. Internally, factors are always stored as integer codes, and these codes *may not correspond to your labels*. The internal codes are totally arbitrary, just for bookkeeping.

The safe way to proceed is to do two coercions:

```
counted$Var1 <- as.numeric(as.character(counted$Var1))
```

and then explicitly convert it back to a factor in your `ggplot2` code:

```
stackedBp <- ggplot(counted,aes(x=factor(Var1),y=Freq,fill=variable))
```

Also, you should keep in mind that sorting the data frame does nothing to change the underlying order associated with the factors in that data frame. To alter that behavior you actually need to use the `ordered` argument to `factor` when specifying the levels directly. Sorting the data frame simply changes the order in which the values are stored, not how the levels are ordered.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should keep the Var1 sorted properly:

`counted.sort$Var1 <- factor(counted.sort$Var1, levels = unique(counted.sort$Var1))`

You can also `?factor` to see options for ordering if the above doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: It's still incorrectly sorted after using `unique`. Justin's `integer` solution works except for the fact that the values of `Var1` increase by 1 or more in converting to integers.

Comment: Did you try
`counted.sort$Var1 <- factor(counted.sort$Var1, levels = unique(counted.sort$Var1), ordered = TRUE)`?

Comment: Yes, that also works. I guess I can't accept both solutions though. Thanks.